# Flesh out the body of print_second function so that it prints the total amount of seconds given the hour,minute,seconds functions parameters

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def print_seconds(hour, minutes,seconds):
   print(____) 
print_seconds(1,2,3)
```

Fill the blank to complete the code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxUiU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need something like this

```py
def print_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
    total_time = hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds
    print(total_time)

print_seconds(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what they are looking for. It looks like we are taking the same class. Thank you Grorge Imerlishvili for your idea which helped me solve this. Just had to leave out the total_time veriable.

```
def print_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
    print(hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds)
```

print_seconds(1,2,3)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32594236)